# Como llamar un stored procedure desde Entity Framework 6 code first

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

Estoy intentado llamar este stored procedure desde C#

```
alter PROCEDURE GetLecturasEnRangoDeFechas
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@fecha as smalldatetime,
@idParteMaquina int,
@inicio int,
@inicioMasDuracion int,
@dia smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @inicioFecha as smalldatetime
set @inicioFecha=CONVERT(smalldatetime, DATEADD(s,@inicio,0))

declare @inicioMasDuracionFecha as smalldatetime
set @inicioMasDuracionFecha=CONVERT(smalldatetime, DATEADD(s,@inicioMasDuracion,0))

-- Insert statements for procedure here
select * from Lectura
where 
cast(Fecha as Date) =cast(@fecha As Date) and
IdParteMaquina=@idParteMaquina and
(Fecha>=@inicioFecha and
Fecha<=@inicioMasDuracionFecha)
or
(@inicioMasDuracionFecha>@dia and
(@inicioFecha+Fecha<=@inicioMasDuracionFecha))

END
GO
```

Codigo C#

```
using(ProduccionContexto pc=new ProduccionContexto())
{
 var lects=pc.Database.SqlQuery<Lectura>("GetLecturasEnRangoDeFechas",fecha,partemaquina.Id, inicio.TotalSeconds, inicioMasDuracion.TotalSeconds, dia);
}
```

Esto me arroja:

```
Procedure or function 'GetLecturasEnRangoDeFechas' expects parameter '@fecha', which was not supplied.
```

Y si lo hago asi:

```
using(ProduccionContexto pc=new ProduccionContexto())
{
 var lects=pc.Database.SqlQuery<Lectura>("GetLecturasEnRangoDeFechas @fecha,@idParteMaquina,@inicio,@inicioMasDuracion,@dia",fecha,partemaquina.Id, inicio.TotalSeconds, inicioMasDuracion.TotalSeconds, dia);
}
```

Me arroja:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@fecha".
```

**Cual es la sintaxis correcta para llamar un SP desde C# EF 6 CodeFirst**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tienes que pasar los parámetros como un objeto `SqlParameter`, no es suficiente con los valores. Así:

```
var lects = pc.Database.SqlQuery<Lectura>(
    "GetLecturasEnRangoDeFechas @fecha, @idParteMaquina, @inicio, @inicioMasDuracion, @dia",
    new SqlParameter("@fecha",fecha),
    new SqlParameter("@idParteMaquina",partemaquina.Id),
    new SqlParameter("@inicio",inicio.TotalSeconds),
    new SqlParameter("@inicioMasDuracion",inicioMasDuracion.TotalSeconds),
    new SqlParameter("@dia",dia));
```

Entity Framework solo tiene acceso al valor, no tiene conocimiento de que la variable `fecha` debe ser asignada al parámetro `@fecha`.

Comment: Le pones SaveChanges?

Answer (score 5):

En lugar de usar el SqlQuery() no seria mejor mapear el procedure a una entidad usando el **MapToStoredProcedures**

[Code First Insert/Update/Delete Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx)

dee sta forma es mucho mas simple indicar que propiedades de la entidad mapean con los parametros

En el articulo explica como realizar este tipo de mapping

saludos

Comment: +1 Tu respuesta es mas elegante, pero creo que solo necesito hacer esto una vez, si llego a requerir muchos Stored Procedures voy a considerar tu sugerencia

Comment: @Leandro como declaras la variable modelBuilder dentro del método que llama al store procedure

Comment: @PedroÁvila no se declara la variable modelbuilder dentro del metodo, la tienes que definir en la clase que hereda de DbContext

Answer (score 5):

Los parámetros los debes especificar como instancias de `SqlParameter`

```
pc.Database.SqlQuery<Lectura>(
    "GetLecturasEnRangoDeFechas @fecha, @idParteMaquina, @inicio, @inicioMasDuracion, @dia",
    new SqlParameter("fecha", fecha),
    new SqlParameter("idParteMaquina", partemaquina.Id),
    new SqlParameter("inicio", inicio.TotalSeconds)
    new SqlParameter("inicioMasDuracion", inicioMasDuracion.TotalSeconds)
    new SqlParameter("dia", dia)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo aplico esta manera para implementar un SP usando EF:

```
empresaEntities _empleados = new empresaEntities();

            var Borrar_Empleado = _empleados.DeleteEmpleado(txtcedula.Text);

            _empleados.SaveChanges();
```

Declaro mi instancia entities, es decir, mi conexión con la base de datos.

Luego declaro una variable que contendrá el SP: "**DeleteEmpleado**", seguido del entities + el nombre del SP y a continuación el parámetro que necesita para su ejecución.

De ultimo pero no menos importante. Se llama al entities y se salvan los cambios con el SavesChanges();

De esa manera funciona para mi.

Espero sea de utilidad esta respuesta para prontas visitas a la pregunta realizada.

Comment: No me queda muy claro de donde sale DeleteEmpleado, en que parte lo declaras, como lo declaras? estamos hablando de Code First?

Comment: El "DeleteEmpleado" es el nombre del SP que estoy implementando. cuando llamas al entities y luego colocas el (.) el automáticamente te despliega los SP que tienes en tu DB.

Comment: De acuerdo, pero en que parte del modelo lo declaras? estas usando model first?

Comment: Si, estoy usando Model First. No necesito declararlo dentro del contexto. Al instanciar y llamar al entities, el me muestra las tablas y SP con los que estoy trabajando en esa BD.

Comment: Ok, edité la pregunta para aclarar que se trata de Codefirst, que a diferencia de ModelFirst, hay que declarar los SP mediante FluentAPI.